# Flutter: A value of type 'Stream<List<object>>' can't be returned from the function 'getCheckInHistory' because it has a return type of 'List<object>'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I'm getting error in returning the response.
I want the type to be `List<ObjectModel>` but it is returning `Stream<List<ObjectModel>>`

I tried `response as List<ObjectModel>` but it is not solving the error. Please help

```
List<ZohoModel> getCheckInHistory() {
  var response =  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("checkIn")
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) =>
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ZohoModel.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
  print(" the response for check-In ${response}");
  return response ;
}
```

the result of printing "response" is :

```
Instance of '_MapStream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, List<ZohoModel>>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better return Stream for most usecase,

```dart
 Stream<List<ZohoModel>> getCheckInHistory() { ..
```

To get the data you can use

```dart
getCheckInHistory().last
```

If you still like to get List, you can convert it to Future method

```dart
  Future<List<ZohoModel>> getCheckInHistory()async {
    var response = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      ....
    return response.last;
  }
```

Comment: I need to get a List<ObjectModel> so that i can use it in ListView.Builder() and display the data coming from firebase.
not im getting a different error in my model 
```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Timestamp' in type cast
```
my model is : 
```class ZohoModel extends Zoho {
  ZohoModel({
    required DateTime time,
  }) : super(time: time);
  factory ZohoModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ZohoModel(
      time:(json['time' as Timestamp]),//DateTime
    );
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "time": time,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)

Comment: And your current error can be converting on TimeStamp , try `time: DateTime.parse(json['time'].toString())` or just `time: json['time'].toDate()`

Answer (score 0):

if You're working with stream builder, make your function return type Stream<List>? and  return response.

```
Stream<List<ZohoModel>> getCheckInHistory() {
      var response =  FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("checkIn")
          .snapshots()
          .map((snapshot) =>
              snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ZohoModel.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
      print(" the response for check-In ${response}");
      return response ;
    }
```

alternatively,

declare list like this outside the function

```
 Stream<List<QuerySnapshot>>? response;
```

then get response in the function without return, using notifyListeners();

```
getCheckInHistory() {
   response =  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("checkIn")
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) =>
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ZohoModel.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
  print(" the response for check-In ${response}");
  notifyListeners();
}
```